# Matlab 'solve' gives different answers on two computers

Tags: matlab, mupad

I have been running code that uses 'solve' on a computer running Matlab R2014a.
The lines in question look like this:

syms z

```
ZETA_NOW=solve((-1/z)*(Sum0 + z^(-2)*Sum1 + z*Sum2 + z^3*Sum3 + z^3*Sum4) + z^2*Thing1 + Thing2 ==0, z);
```

As you can see, I'm trying to solve for z. All the other variables listed in the argument given to solve (Sum0, Sum1, Thing1, etc) are scalars calculated previously.

When I run my program on the computer that has R2014a installed and display ZETA_NOW, a set of five real and complex solutions is visible. The real solution is the one I want, and I am certain that it is correct based on comparison with known results.

When I run my program on the computer running R2014b and again display ZETA_NOW, the five answers are shown as:

```
RootOf(big equation)
RootOf(big equation)
.
.
RootOf(big equation)
```

Furthermore, for some input values, there is no real solution given, which was not the case for the same input values when running this on the other computer.

Is there some option for 'solve' that I need to change, such as the number of iterations allowed?

Comment: Is the only difference the Matlab versions? Are there differences in processor, OS, etc. ?

Comment: For the computer on which the program works, the processor is a 2.6 GHz Intel Core i7 and the OS is Mac OS X ver. 10.9.4. For the computer on which the program doesn't work, the processor is an Intel Xeon CPU E5-2609 v2, and the OS is Red Hat Linux 6.

Comment: Edit your question to provide complete runnable code so that others can replicate this. No need to provide all of the code used to produce `Sum0 `... -either provide the full floating point values (`sprintf('%.17g',Sum0)`), symbolic values, or just evaluate the equation put to `solve` before passing it in and provide us with what that returns (on both versions of Matlab if they are different).